# can't select specific elements from data contained in <?!=JSON.stringify(dataFromServerTemplate) ?>

Tags: javascript, json, html, google-apps-script

I have a problem with JSON format. I'm new at this kind of stuff so I can't figure out which is the problem. In google app script I have this get function

```
function doGet() {
    var htmlTemplate = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('html');
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_cj_HO2oN6CYe_Pb7Cy8S3yVtwKW8Efr-Sdyf1Sk8Ts/edit#gid=2009573145");

    htmlTemplate.dataFromServerTemplate = makeJSON(getRowsData_(ss.getSheetByName("Foglio8"),getExportOptions()),getExportOptions());
    var htmlOutput = htmlTemplate.evaluate().setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME)
        .setTitle('sample');
    return htmlOutput;
}
```

Now, here is the part of the HTML which isn't working

```
<div>
    <p id="tx"></p>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var data = <?!=JSON.stringify(dataFromServerTemplate) ?>; 
    function caric(){
        document.getElementById("tx").innerText= data.saldo;}
</script>
</body>
```

Function `caric()` runs `onload` of the page. "saldo" is actually contained in this JSON.

If I use `data.saldo`I receives `undefined` but if I only use `data` it works and prints everything that is contained in the JSON.

Do you know what I'm doing wrong?
Thanks

Comment: Can you provide the console output of  `data` might be the `data` doesn't have the property called `saldo`

Comment: "isn't working" is not a *clear problem statement*. You need to narrow down your problem and provide a [mcve]. Start by figuring out which program the problem is in. View Source in your browser. Look at the HTML (with embedded JavaScript) that is generated. Is that what you expect it to be? If so, ask a question about that generated code. If not, then ask a question about how to generate the code you actually want (showing how what you want differs from what you get).

Comment: "If I use data.saldoI receives undefined but if I only use data it works and prints everything that is contained in the JSON." — So what us what that JSON is.

Answer (score -1):

JSON.stringify produces a string not an object.  In your server code you should do something like this.

```
var obj = { name: "me", gender: "male", eyes: "blue" };
htmlTemplate.dataFromServerTemplate = JSON.stringify(obj);
```

And on the client side this

```
var data = JSON.parse(<?= dataFromServerTemplate ?>);
(function caric(){
    document.getElementById("tx").innerText= data.name;}());
```

Comment: "JSON.stringify produces a string" — It produces a string in the server-side JavaScript. `<?!` then causes it to be output to the HTML document. Since it is inside a `<script>` the content of that string will be parsed as JavaScript source code (probably an object literal). Trying to pass that though `JSON.parse` will stringify it and try to do the equivalent of `JSON.parse("[Object object]");` which will throw an error.

Comment: Yes this would also work     var data = <?!= dataFromServerTemplate ?>;